# How to persistently map Capslock to ESC and Ctrl so that it still works after suspend/resume

Tags: 20.04, suspend, remapping, capslock

I'm using the following lines in my `~/.xprofile` on Ubuntu 20.04 to map <kbd>Capslock</kbd> to <kbd>ESC</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>:

```bsh
# make CapsLock behave like Ctrl:                                
setxkbmap -option ctrl:nocaps
# make short-pressed Ctrl behave like Escape:
xcape -e 'Control_L=Escape'
```

which works perfectly fine for me.

My issue is that it does not survive suspend/resume reliably. For this, I've tried 2 different solutions:

### 1. Via a script `capsmap` put into `/usr/lib/systemd/system-sleep/`

```bsh
#!/bin/bash                                                            
                                                                       
case "$1" in                                                           
    pre)                                                               
      #code execution BEFORE sleeping/hibernating/suspending     
    ;;                                                                 
    post)                                                              
      #code execution AFTER resuming                             
      /usr/bin/echo "executing: /usr/bin/setxkbmap -option ctrl:nocaps"
      /usr/bin/setxkbmap -option ctrl:nocaps                           
      /usr/bin/echo "executing: /usr/bin/xcape -e 'Control_L=Escape'"  
      /usr/bin/xcape -e 'Control_L=Escape'                             
                                                                       
    ;;                                                                 
esac                                                                   
                                                                       
exit 0
```

I've made the script executable with `sudo chmod +x capsmap` and can see from the logs that it is called at the appropriate time:

```bsh
$ journalctl
...
Okt 09 13:29:12 nb systemd-sleep[401221]: System resumed.
Okt 09 13:29:12 nb kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Device revision is 5
Okt 09 13:29:12 nb kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Secure boot is enabled
Okt 09 13:29:12 nb kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: OTP lock is enabled
Okt 09 13:29:12 nb kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: API lock is enabled
Okt 09 13:29:12 nb kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Debug lock is disabled
Okt 09 13:29:12 nb kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Minimum firmware build 1 week 10 2014
Okt 09 13:29:12 nb kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Found device firmware: intel/ibt-11-5.sfi
Okt 09 13:29:12 nb systemd-sleep[401287]: executing: /usr/bin/setxkbmap -option ctrl:nocaps
Okt 09 13:29:12 nb systemd-sleep[401288]: Cannot open display "default display"
Okt 09 13:29:12 nb systemd-sleep[401291]: executing: /usr/bin/xcape -e 'Control_L=Escape'
Okt 09 13:29:12 nb systemd-sleep[401293]: Unable to connect to X11 display. Is $DISPLAY set?
Okt 09 13:29:12 nb systemd[1]: systemd-suspend.service: Succeeded.
Okt 09 13:29:12 nb systemd[1]: Finished Suspend.
Okt 09 13:29:12 nb systemd[1]: Stopped target Sleep.
Okt 09 13:29:12 nb systemd[1]: Reached target Suspend.
Okt 09 13:29:12 nb systemd[1]: Stopped target Suspend.
...
```

However, the mapping only sometimes applies. Quite often, <kbd>Capslock</kbd> just behaves as normal.

### 2. Via a systemd service

I've added a service file `capsmap.service` to `etc/systemd/system/` with the following content:

```bsh
[Unit]
Description=Map Capslock to ESC and Ctrl
After=suspend.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/capsmap
TimeoutSec=0
StandardOutput=syslog

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target suspend.target
```

with the file `/usr/local/bin/capsmap` as

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# make CapsLock behave like Ctrl:
/usr/bin/echo "executing: /usr/bin/setxkbmap -option ctrl:nocaps"
/usr/bin/setxkbmap -option ctrl:nocaps

# make short-pressed Ctrl behave like Escape:
/usr/bin/echo "executing: /usr/bin/xcape -e 'Control_L=Escape'"
/usr/bin/xcape -e 'Control_L=Escape'

exit 0
```

then enabled the service with `sudo systemctl enable capsmap.service`.

Also in this case, I can see with `journalctl` that the script was executed successfully, but the normal <kbd>Capslock</kbd> behavior is still present.

```bsh
$journalctl
...
Okt 09 13:07:56 nb systemd[1]: Stopped target Suspend.                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
Okt 09 13:07:56 nb NetworkManager[1049]: <info>  [1633777676.0331] manager: sleep: wake requested (sleeping: yes  enabled: yes)                                                                                                                                                   
Okt 09 13:07:56 nb ModemManager[1137]: <info>  [sleep-monitor] system is resuming                                                                                                                                                                                                 
Okt 09 13:07:56 nb NetworkManager[1049]: <info>  [1633777676.0332] device (enp0s31f6): state change: activated -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')                                                                                                       
Okt 09 13:07:56 nb systemd[1761]: Stopped target Bluetooth.                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
Okt 09 13:07:56 nb upowerd[1344]: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-8                          
Okt 09 13:07:56 nb capsmap[378798]: executing: /usr/bin/setxkbmap -option ctrl:nocaps                                                                                                                                                                                             
Okt 09 13:07:56 nb systemd[1761]: Reached target Bluetooth.                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
Okt 09 13:07:56 nb NetworkManager[1049]: <info>  [1633777676.0498] dhcp4 (enp0s31f6): canceled DHCP transaction                                                                                                                                                                   
Okt 09 13:07:56 nb capsmap[378799]: Cannot open display "default display"                                                                                                                                                                                                         
Okt 09 13:07:56 nb NetworkManager[1049]: <info>  [1633777676.0498] dhcp4 (enp0s31f6): state changed bound -> done                                                                                                                                                                 
Okt 09 13:07:56 nb avahi-daemon[1041]: Withdrawing address record for 192.168.178.54 on enp0s31f6.                                       
Okt 09 13:07:56 nb avahi-daemon[1041]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface enp0s31f6.IPv4 with address 192.168.178.54.                                                                                                                                                      
Okt 09 13:07:56 nb avahi-daemon[1041]: Interface enp0s31f6.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.                                             
Okt 09 13:07:56 nb avahi-daemon[1041]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::778b:d324:d55d:a503 on enp0s31f6.                                                                                                                                                                     
Okt 09 13:07:56 nb avahi-daemon[1041]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface enp0s31f6.IPv6 with address fe80::778b:d324:d55d:a503.  
Okt 09 13:07:56 nb avahi-daemon[1041]: Interface enp0s31f6.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.                                                                                                                                                                                      
Okt 09 13:07:56 nb systemd[1]: Started Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status.                                                                  
Okt 09 13:07:56 nb capsmap[378800]: executing: /usr/bin/xcape -e 'Control_L=Escape'                                                                                                                                                                                               
Okt 09 13:07:56 nb NetworkManager[1049]: <info>  [1633777676.0545] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL                 
Okt 09 13:07:56 nb capsmap[378805]: Unable to connect to X11 display. Is $DISPLAY set?                                                                                                                                                                                            
Okt 09 13:07:56 nb kernel: kauditd_printk_skb: 9 callbacks suppressed                                                                                                                                                                                                             
Okt 09 13:07:56 nb kernel: audit: type=1107 audit(1633777676.068:1737): pid=1047 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_signal"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/30" interface="org.fr>
                            exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=103 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'                                                                                                                                                                                    
Okt 09 13:07:56 nb kernel: audit: type=1107 audit(1633777676.068:1738): pid=1047 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_signal"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/30" interface="org.fr>
                            exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=103 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'                                                                                                                                                                                    
Okt 09 13:07:56 nb audit[1047]: USER_AVC pid=1047 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_signal"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/30" interface="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.Connec>
                                 exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=103 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'                                                                                                                                                                               
Okt 09 13:07:56 nb audit[1047]: USER_AVC pid=1047 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_signal"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/30" interface="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.Connec>
                                 exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=103 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'                                                                                                                                                                               
Okt 09 13:07:56 nb systemd[1]: capsmap.service: Succeeded.   
...
```